# Iterating through json list in Django template

Tags: python, json, django, list, jinja2

I am passing the following context in my Django template :

```
context = {'test': custom_json_list}
```

And the output of custom_json_list is this :

```
{'pc_16530587071502': [{'people_count_entry__sum': None}],
 'pc_17100675958928': [{'people_count_entry__sum': None},
                       {'people_count_entry__sum': None},
                       {'people_count_entry__sum': None},
                       {'people_count_entry__sum': None},
                       {'people_count_entry__sum': None},
                       {'people_count_entry__sum': None},
                       {'people_count_entry__sum': None},
                       {'people_count_entry__sum': None},
                       {'people_count_entry__sum': 4},
                       {'people_count_entry__sum': None},
                       {'people_count_entry__sum': None},
                       {'people_count_entry__sum': None},
                       {'people_count_entry__sum': None},
                       {'people_count_entry__sum': None},
                       {'people_count_entry__sum': None},
                       {'people_count_entry__sum': None}]}
```

I want to display the data in the following format:

```
'pc_16530587071502' : NONE
'pc_17100675958928' : None
'pc_17100675958928' : None
'pc_17100675958928' : None
'pc_17100675958928' : None
'pc_17100675958928' : None
'pc_17100675958928' : None
'pc_17100675958928' : 4
'pc_17100675958928' : None
'pc_17100675958928' : None
'pc_17100675958928' : None
```

How can I proceed with the syntax so that I can see the data in this format.

The only thing I was able to decipher is this :

```
{% for key, value in test.items %}
     {{ key }} <br />
     {{ value }} <br />
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. All you need to do is to iterate through `value` as well:

```
{% for key, value in test.items %}
    {% for dct in value %}
        {% for k, sum in dct.items %}
            {{ key }}: {{ sum }} <br />
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried but still no luck :( am I doing something wrong here :)

Here's my code : 

`{{ test }}
<br>
{% for key, value in test.items %}
    {% for k, sum in value.items %}
        {{ key }}: {{ sum }} <br />
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}`

- {{ test }} gives me the entire output. 
- But when I am trying the piece of code you have shared with me it doesn't show anything on the template.

Am I still missing something?

Comment: aah ... Now I get it. So looking at the syntax it was just I have to reiterate again through the dict :) Thank you very much for the help +1